# Finding the actual source for an error message from a template instantiation / type deduction

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting some error in a templated function of some 3rd party library that I am trying to build.

MSVC points to the function and told me that I am doing something wrong for a specific call. How can I know at which call exactly the error happens?

---

If it matters, this is the function:

```
template <typename T>
std::string ToString(T number) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << std::setprecision(NUM_TO_STRING_PRECISION);
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}
```

The error is:

> Error C2088   '<<': illegal for class

Comment: Is that the complete error?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yup

Comment: The docs say that error only happens in C code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2088 How many places is it used? You might start commenting them out til you find the one that causes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I know at which call exactly the error happens?

Not really with [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio), but let's look at a simple [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6669ab29a1b3d744):

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    Foo() = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo> vfoo(15);
    (void)vfoo;
}
```

GCC g++ outputs these error messages:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/vector:63:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<true>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = Foo*; _Size = long unsigned int]':
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:583:20:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = Foo*; _Size = long unsigned int]'
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:645:44:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = Foo*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = Foo]'
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1347:36:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_initialize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = Foo; _Alloc = std::allocator<Foo>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_vector.h:285:30:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = Foo; _Alloc = std::allocator<Foo>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<Foo>]'
main.cpp:9:29:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/7.1.0/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:548:37: error: use of deleted function 'Foo::Foo()'
    return std::fill_n(__first, __n, _ValueType());
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:4:5: note: declared here
     Foo() = delete;
     ^~~
```

IIRC it's very similar in visual studio. Just open the raw output tab, and go to the very last `note`, which probably contains the *real source* of the error.

---

<sub>MSVC results with [rextester](http://rextester.com/LLKS68101). Again the very last notes for `source_file.cpp` point to the real source of the error.</sub>

Comment: @HumamHelfawi De nada ;-)